# Android - Set Text on 'Loading" ProgressBar from strings.xml

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am working on a Live Project. and we are designing it for 2 languages.
So, I have to take each text from `strings.xml`
When I click on any link and when a view is loading it is showing `ProgressDialog` showing `Loading...`
The code for that is,

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen_menu.this,"","Loading...", true, false);
```

but, I want it from from `strings.xml`

How can I do that??
I tried,

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen_menu.this,"",R.string.loading_data, true, false);
```

but, It is showing error at `R.string.loading_data` because it is `int` value.

Please Help..!

Thank You..:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using inside the **activity class** you can use the below source code.

`ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen_menu.this,"",getResources().getString(R.string.pleaseWait),true,false);`

*(or)*

If you are using normal class, Inside the constructor initialize the activity as parameter then use like below code.

`ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen_menu.this,"",(context).getResources().getString(R.string.pleaseWait),true,false);`

Comment: But, if i use this in non-activity file, then it gives an error that create method getResources or getString..whats the solution for it? Your another solution not working..:(

Comment: you should get the activiy context or application context like as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getString(R.string.loading_data)
```

Comment: But, if i use this in non-activity file, then it gives an error that create method getResources or getString..whats the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

like following way.

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen_menu.this,"",getResources().getString(R.string.pleaseWait),true,false);
```

**UPDATE:**
Above solutions is useful from activity class. From non-activity class just need to cast to context like following way

```
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen_menu.this,"",context.getResources().getString(R.string.pleaseWait),true,false);
```

Comment: But, if i use this in non-activity file, then it gives an error that create method getResources or getString.

Comment: whats the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen_menu.this,"",R.string.loading_data, true, false);
```

to this:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen_menu.this,"",getString(R.string.loading_data), true, false);
```

Comment: But, if i use this in non-activity file, then it gives an error that create method getResources or getString..whats the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

getString(R.string.loading_data);

Comment: But, if i use this in non-activity file, then it gives an error that create method getResources or getString..whats the solution for it?

Comment: Use like this Context.getString(R.string.Loading);